# How ro increase AS3 getcamera quality

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

i want to create a flash that will display your webcam. its working but the thing is the quality is bad. i use AS3 and the dimensions is 640x480. how can it improve? i checked my camera throught ray-ban virtual mirror flash app on their website and the quality here is so good http://www.ray-ban.com/usa/science/virtual-mirror,

here is my code.

```
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.Video;

var cam:Camera = new Camera();
var vid:Video = new Video(640,480);

cam.setMode(640,480,60);
cam = Camera.getCamera();
vid.attachCamera(cam);

addChild(vid);
```

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#setQuality%28%29

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, i tried it and the quality didnt improve. i did something like this: setQuality(16384,100); what am i doing wrong?

Comment: maybe setQuality(0,100);